# Finding the maximum value of primary key field after extracting certain characters in MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to enter primary key values in MySql database something like the following.

```
B001_V_WB_001
B002_V_WB_002
B003_V_WB_003
B004_V_WB_004
B005_V_WB_005

....
....

B011_V_WB_010
B010_V_WB_011

...
...

B100_V_WB_100
B101_V_WB_101

...
...

B1000_V_WB_1000
B1001_V_WB_1001
```

and alike. I need to span through all the rows of this column and extract from the right to the very first occurrence of an underscore `-` and find the maximum from all the rows in this column.

Is there a best way to do so in MySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,'_',-1) AS SIGNED)) from foo;
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be better though, if it could handle values bigger than integers.

Comment: The better solution would be to use proper sequences but sadly MySQL doesn't support sequences.  Another reason to love postgresql.